# Match multiple paths in artifactory repo

Tags: docker, artifactory, artifacts, artifactory-query-lang

So I'm trying to write a search_spec.json file to exclude all docker images with path **/latest* or **/develop* im my artifactory repo. However I cannot find a solution to exclude multiple paths from the search results. With the current solution I'm getting a 400 from artifactory. Any ideas?

```js
{
   "files":[
      {
         "aql":{
            "items.find":{
               "repo":{
                  "$eq":"my-docker-repo"
               },
               "path":{
                  "$nmatch":"**/latest*",
                  "$nmatch":"**/develop*"
               },
               "updated":{
                  "$before":"8w"
               },
               "stat.downloaded":{
                  "$before":"12w"
               }
            }
         },
         "recursive":"true",
         "sortBy":[
            "created"
         ],
         "limit":10000
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [compound criteria](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-CompoundingCriteria) for that, using an `$and` operator.

In your example, change -

```json
"path":{
   "$nmatch":"**/latest*",
   "$nmatch":"**/develop*"
},
```

to -

```json
"$and":[
   {
      "path":{
         "$nmatch":"**/latest*"
      }
   },{
      "path":{
         "$nmatch":"**/develop*"
      }
   }
],
```